# Sturm-Liouville operator with Dirichlet BC

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, differential-operators

I am trying to understand why Sturm-Liouville operator $$L(f)(x)=f''(x)-p(x)f(x)$$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions on $[a,b]$ is unbounded.

$f$ is twice continuously differentiable, $p(x)>0$ is continuous. Where does the trouble come from?

Comment: Take $f_k(x) = e^{ikx}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n = \sin\left(n\pi\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)$. Then
$$
              Lf_n = -\left(\frac{n^2\pi^2}{(b-a)^2}+p\right)f_n \\
$$
If $P$ is a uniform bound for $p$ on $[a,b]$, and if $n$ is large enough,
$$
               |Lf_n| \ge \left(\frac{n^2\pi^2}{(b-a)^2}-P\right)|f_n| \\
                 \|Lf_n\| \ge \left(\frac{n^2\pi^2}{(b-a)^2}-P\right)\|f_n\|
$$

Comment: Great, big thank you.

Comment: @Marina : You're welcome. :)